Check Point Anti-Bot обнаруживает попытки заражения при запуске Яндекс.Браузера
Check Point Anti-Bot обнаруживает попытки заражения и выдает сообщения вида:
{
  "Имя защиты": "Infecting_URL.RS.TC.14a8olbL",
  "Принятая мера": "Предотвращено",
  "URL": "https://zagent2680.yg5sjx5kzy.com",
  "Имя процесса": "/Applications/Yandex.app/Contents/Frameworks/Yandex Framework.framework/Versions/24.7.6.970/Helpers/Yandex Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Yandex Helper",
  "Идентификатор процесса": 98729,
  "Имя пользователя": "alber.aleksandrov",
  "Имя родительского процесса": "/Applications/Yandex.app/Contents/MacOS/Yandex",
  "Идентификатор родительского процесса": 98698,
  "Имя родительского пользователя": "alber.aleksandrov",
  "Время первого заражения": "9 окт. 2024 г., 20:04",
  "Время последнего заражения": "9 окт. 2024 г., 20:04"
}

ОС: Sequioa 15.0.1. Уведомления Check Point начинает выдавать после того, как запускается Яндекс.Браузер (последняя версия).
Не могу понять, в чем дело. Yandex Helper не гуглится.
Что это вообще такое и как это полечить?
